# Apply a map to DataFrame rows which are NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a mapping to a Pandas DataFrame, where some rows in one specific column are `NaN`. These are left overs from a prior mapping.

```
mymap = defaultdict(str)
mymap["a"] = "-1 test"
mymap["b"] = "-2 test"
mymap["c"] = "-3 test"

df[ df["my_infos"].isnull() ] = df["something"].map(lambda ip: map_function(ip, mymap))
```

Here is the function:

```
def map_function(ip, mymap):
    # do stuff
    for key, value in mymap.iteritems():
           # do stuff
           return stuff
    return other_stuff
```

This terminates after it iterates over the whole column, but shows:

> File
>   "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py",
>   line 527, in _setitem_with_indexer
>       raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value ' ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Is this the correct way to select all rows in the `my_infos` column, which are NaN? I somehow sense... that's not the case.

Comment: IIUC you need to mask both sides: `df.loc[ df["my_infos"].isnull() ] = df.loc[df['my_infos'].isnull(), "something"].map(lambda ip: map_function(ip, mymap))` The problem is that you're masking the left side but not the right side so the shapes don't match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can select `NaN` values to both sides and then `map`:

```
df[ df["my_infos"].isnull() ] = 
df.ix[ df["my_infos"].isnull(), "something"].map(lambda ip: map_function(ip, mymap))
```